# C# PropertyPath

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
new PropertyPath("(RotateTransform.Angle)")
```

why do we need the brackets around  RotateTransform.Angle? And why sometimes we don't need brackets around it?

Cheers

Comment: You know you can use the static properties on the type new PropertyPath(RotateTransform.AngleProperty);

Comment: I had a vague idea but no I didn't! Cool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this: [MSDN Binding.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) the brackets indicate that the path refers to an attached property. Since attached-properties are not declared on the dependency-object itself, the binding might need an indicator to distinct dependency-properties from attached properties.

/edit: sorry, gave you a german link, see my update.

Comment: thank you. I believe this is what I didn't know "To bind to an attached property, place parentheses around the attached property. For example, to bind to the attached property DockPanel.Dock, the syntax is Path=(DockPanel.Dock)." From the link above

Comment: Note that the () do not denote "attached vs. not"; their purpose is to change the "." from separating properties to separating types.  Thus "Path=BorderBrush.Color" could be written as "Path=BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color)".  It's just that you *must* use () with attached properties, since otherwise there's no way to find the property you wanted (since it's not on the previous object).